# Is it possible to add request URLs to the php-fpm.log

Tags: ubuntu, php, logging, nginx

At present, I get entries such as the following in my php7.0-fpm.log

```
[11-Sep-2017 13:32:17] WARNING: [pool www] child 28808, script
'/var/www/mysite/public/index.php' (request: "GET /index.php")
executing too slow (91.676235 sec), logging
```

But instead of just seeing the php script that was executed, I want to see the actual URL for the request. (We direct all PHP requests via index.php so this logging is currently of limited use and requires some hit-or-miss marrying up with the nginx access log.)

Answer (score 2):

The default configuration loads all .conf files from the `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/` directory.

Create a new file `logging.conf` with the following contents:

```
[www]
access.format = "%t \"%m %{REQUEST_URI}e%Q%q\" %s %{mili}d %{kilo}M"
```

The key is the `%{REQUEST_URI}e`; this pulls what eventually becomes `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`